# Wordpress Plugin Appends Div before content

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to attach a div from a voting plugin before the content is generated on both the excerpt and the content of a post. Here's what I have in my plugin:

```
if (get_option('ilt_onPage') == '1') {
  function putILikeThis($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_single() && !in_category('3') ) {
      $likethisbox.= getILikeThis('put');
    }
    $content = $likethisbox . $content;
    return $content;
  }
  add_filter('the_content', putILikeThis);
}

if (get_option('ilt_onPage') == '1') {
  function putILikeThis1($excerpt) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_archive() && in_category('3') ) {
      $likethisbox.= getILikeThis('put');
    }
    $excerpt = $likethisbox . $excerpt;
    return $excerpt;
  }
  add_filter('the_excerpt', putILikeThis1);
}
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What's actually going wrong? One thing that makes me vaguely suspicious is that `in_category('3')` -- should that be `in_category(3)` instead? WordPress might be looking for a category _named_ '3', not the category with the ID of 3.

Comment: Its either embedding it in all categories or randomly places it in odd posts. Its all very random! I've tried all variations of the In_category call and its still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Several key things were going wrong. Code I used here:

```
if (get_option('ilt_onPage') == '1') {
function putILikeThis($content) {
    if(!is_feed() && !is_page() && in_category('revocations') ) { //it now sees the category!
        $likethisbox= getILikeThis('put'); //No .= period behind the =
    }
    return $likethisbox . $content; //I was putting these into a $ when needed to return them
}
add_filter('the_content', 'putILikeThis'); }
```